# Choose a word randomly from input, without storage

Tags: java, random

It is a practice assignment (optional). The question is asking to

> "Write a program RandomWord.java that reads a sequence of words from
> standard input and prints one of those words uniformly at random. Do
> not store the words in an array or list. Instead, use Knuth’s method:
> when reading the ith word, select it with probability 1/i to be the
> champion, replacing the previous champion. After reading all of the
> words, print the surviving champion."

And this is my very first time writing Java.

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom;

public class RandomWord{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String challenger = "";
        String champ = StdIn.readString();
        //StdOut.println(champ);

        int count = 1;
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            count++;
            challenger = StdIn.readString();
            //StdOut.println(champ);

        if (StdRandom.bernoulli((1.0/count))) {
            champ = challenger;
            }
            else {
                }
                //StdOut.println(champ);
                }
         StdOut.println(champ);
            }}
```

(algs4.jar library is used: https://coursera.cs.princeton.edu/algs4/assignments/hello/specification.php)

```
javac -classpath ".:../hello/.lift/algs4.jar" RandomWord.java
java -cp ".:../hello/.lift/algs4.jar" RandomWord
a b c d
```

Comment: This code produces results that don't conform to the requirements.  I don't think it's ready for review yet.

Comment: Understandable part of requirements: *print one of the words read*. In dire need of clarification: a) what is a *word* b) how to handle words occurring more than once in the input c) *[process one input] uniformly at random*.

Comment: still need variable `champion` to keep selected word. And other variable to keep result `StdRandom.bernoulli()` for this word - to compare it with `StdRandom.bernoulli` for next words.

Comment: As others have said, this is not ready for review. The code doesn't do what the specification requires. Code review is not the same as "I don't know what to do, please help".

Answer (score 1):

You missed more important part of problem.

You need variables to keep `champion word`, `champion result` and comparte it with result for new word, and replace values in `champion word`, `champion result`.

I can't test it but it could be something like code below.
But I'm not sure if it should use `1/i` (different for every word) or `1/number_of_all_words` (the same for every word)

But this example works only for input with 5 words. For any number of words it may need to use `while (!StdIn.isEmpty())`  and something for `1/i`

```java
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom;

public class RandomWord {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double champion_result = 0;
        String champion_word = "";
        
        for(int i = 1; i<5; i++) {
            String current_word = StdIn.readString();
 
            double current_result = StdRandom.bernoulli((double)1/i)
 
            if(current_result > champion_result) {
                champion_result = current_result;
                champiop_word = current_word;
            }
        }

        StdOut.println(champion_word);
    }
}
```

Comment: if(current_result > champion_word) { Here, what are you comparing? what is the index for the comparison? Thank you

Comment: my mistake it should be `current_result > champion_result`.Fixed

Comment: double current_result = StdRandom.bernoulli((double)1/i);
This line gives an error how should I fix it, and in general how could I know which part is actually causing an error? Apologise for the stupid question

Comment: I can't run it to see problem. But full error message should say what can be the problem and you should read full error. You can always split code to smaller parts - ie. `double val = 1/i;`, etc. and see which part will give error. And you can use `println()` to check what you have in variables - maybe there is wrong value.  I see only that I forgot `;` at the end of this line - and this can make problem.

Comment: Please refrain from answering low-quality questions that are likely to get closed.  Once you've answered, that [limits what can be done to improve the question](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body), making it more likely that your efforts are wasted.  It's better to wait until the question is properly ready before you answer!